# Problem Mod rewrite in directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with mod rewrite.

I made urls like this:
www.domain.com/test/23/24
that go to this:
www.domain.com/test.php/23/24
Then i blocked the map test2 so that will not redirect
but now i want to sent this:
www.domain.com/test2/test/23/24
to:
www.domain.com/test2/test.php/23/24
I can't work this out i tried al lot but can't fint it

This is what i have in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test2 - [L,NC]

RewriteCond $1 !images|downloads
RewriteRule ^([^\./]+)/(.*) /$1.php/$2 [L]
```

EDIT:
The last rewriterule is the one sending every fictive map to the php file in the root
The first is making sure that doesnt happen with test2.
then i need that for every subdirectory in test2 it is send to teh phpfile with same name in the directory test2
Example:
test2/test/34/34/24/ to test2/test.php/34/34/24

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with urls like /aaa/bbb/ccc/dddd and it worked going to /aaa/bbb.php/ccc/ddd and also bbb/ccc/ddd going to bbb.php/ccc/ddd

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^extra=(.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ /$1/%1\? [R=301,L,NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([^/]+/)?([^/\.]+)((:?/[^/]+){2,})
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1%2.php\?extra=%3 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Sorry then.. I'll try to try later in my server.
Edit: I just tried on my server and it worked fine, by the way you just need this Rule:
**RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?test/(.*) $1/test.php/$2 [L,NC]**

Comment: like i said in the edit in my post test2 is a map and test is a fictiv map dat has to go to php file with same name as mapname. And that is variable

Comment: So, Your path is something like xxx/yyy/www/zzz Where 'xxx' is optional 'yyy' is a text and 'www' and 'zzz' are numbers? am I right? because, if you don't have a pattern you can't build a regexp.

Comment: xxx is or name phpfile or name directory
yyy is in case xxx phpfile numbers or words that are variables where i look at in the phpfile in case xxx is directory that is a phpfile name in that directory
zzz and www are numbers or words that are variables used in phpfile

Comment: It is not working when aaa is suposed to go to file it doesnt in the error log is see that actualy its stil looking for a directory with that name when the second dir is the file de link in top changes to xxx.php?extra=/yyy/zzz and must be xxx/yyy.php/zzz and it must not change in top

Comment: i have tried to do it without the R=301 and changed {2,} in a * in this case xxx/yyy/zzz goes to xxx/yyy.php/zzz but the other one doesnt work only if its just xxx

Comment: It's because your 'pattern' is really difficult, can you try to make paths more simple? like: aaa/bbb/vars/xxx/yyy to: aaa/bbb.php/xxx/yyy

Comment: actualy it is not that difficult i think.
I have just a site where every link is like this.
aaa/bbb/../ccc
aaa is the name of the php file where i want it to direct to.
rest are variables i use in php file
and i have a map with the admin in it.
admin/aaa/bbb/../ccc here aaa is again the php file and the rest variables i use in the file.
and i have a few directories with images and so that need no redirection at all.

Comment: if the first part is always the php is fine.. but you said that in aaa/bbbb/cccc/... aaa can be a directory and bbb the php file.. so that makes it more complex.

Comment: is there not something like this. Look if aaa is a directory. If it is rewrite url bbb to bbb.php if it is not rewrite url aaa to aaa.php.
Or if that is not possible if that is aaa=admin do bbb to bbb.php else do aaa to aaa.php that has to be possible not?